# how to detect shift keystroke in c?

Tags: c, winapi

I try to detect `shift` keystrokes in `C` with `winapi` `Control.ModifierKeys` in `C#`
is there any equivalent function in `C` to this `C#` function:

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift ) { 
  ...
}
```

I want to detect `shift` keystrokes in `C`.

Comment: That snippet doesn't detect key strokes, it detects key state.  What do you *really* want to detect?

Comment: He probably meant state.  That is how ModifierKeys is used in C# at least.  He wants to know if the Shift key is currently being pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetAsyncKeyState

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(VS.85).aspx

Comment: GetKeyState() should be used, there's an important difference.

Comment: Yes but if he wants the state of the press at the time of the function then he needs to use GetAsyncKeyState.  GetKeyState returns the state of the keys when the original event (click for example or keypress) was sent.

Answer (score 1):

I believe getAsyncKeyState does pretty much exactly what you want.